# Fixed div at the top of a page

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I'm trying to create a page with a fixed div above the main div. The main div should be below the fixed div but instead it overlaps the fixed div.

Adding `margin-top` positions the main div below the fixed div but, it also clips the same amount off of the bottom of the page.

What am I doing wrong?

[Live Demo](http://thetesting.site/fixeddiv/fixedheader.html)

```css
body {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed; 
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
.main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.expand {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  fixed div line 1<br />
  fixed div line 2<br />
  fixed div line 3<br />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="expand"></div> <!-- For demo purposes only -->
</div>
```

Comment: add margin-top property to the css rules for the main div.

Comment: Joshua, Thanks for the reply. I know I can move the main div down with a top margin but isn't there a way to do it "automatically"? That is, do it without having to set the margin such that it shows properly. Unless I figure something else out, I'll add an onload function and use the fixed div's height to set the margin for the main div. That way I don't have change the CSS if the fixed div's height changes - either because I change it or because it changes do to lower screen resolution or zoom in or out. I want it to be dynamic so that it can be used on a lot of different devices.

Comment: ah ok. I understand. there is no good way to do this with only css. you can copy the header element. remove the position:fixed for the copy and set opacity to zero. in this case it's inside the flow and pushes the main-div as far as it is below the fixed header. But you have double content... SEO don't like this... and so on. better use javascript these days to solve this problem. but keep in mind: you need a solution for clients with deactivated javascript ;)

Comment: Right - the ol' JavaScript not enabled issue -- i have just about given up making comparable pages for disabled JavaScript. Every browser and release that I've seen lately has JavaScript enabled by default. Things like the one we are discussing may only be doable, as you said, with JavaScript. I'm going to start including a noscript tag that simply says "This web site uses JavaScript and you have it disabled. Please enabled JavaScript and reload this page."

Comment: your decision. you can do this very easily by adding a css class "no-js" to the html-tag and remove it with javascript. now you can define css rules for js enabled users and js disabled users: header-div-selector { position:fixed; } .no-js header-div-selector { position:absolute; }. that's all.

Comment: Had not thought of that - good idea. I can set the element to position: relative and if JS is enabled, I can change it to fixed (and set the margin-top of the main div to the height of the fixed div.) Yeah, I like that approach. Though there can be times where you have to use JS for something without a good alternative so there may still be a need for a noscript tag. Thanks for the idea. I'll go that route.

Comment: @BobN I've posted an answer below, please let me know if this does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect that you're looking for, you can use a combination of `display: table` on a parent and `display: table-row` on each of the direct descendants.

- Set `height: 100%` on `html, body, .wrap, .main, .inner`.
- Wrap the current "parents" in a div with class `.wrap`
- Set `display: table` and `width: 100%` on `.wrap`.
- Set `display: table-row` on `.fixed, .main`
- Wrap the text content of `.main` in a div with class `.inner`
- Set `overflow: auto` on `.inner`

This way, no matter what the size of the top div is, the `.main` will always be underneath `.fixed`.

`display: table` is supported by [IE > 7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) and all other modern browsers.

```css
html, body, .wrap, .main, .inner {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;    /* Include border width in sizing */
  border: 8px solid #00FFFF; /* Use a border instead of relying on margins */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed, .main {
  display: table-row;
}
.inner {
  overflow: auto;
}
.expand { height: 800px; }
.fixed { background-color: #C0C0C0; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="fixed">
    fixed div line 1<br />
    fixed div line 2<br />
    fixed div line 3<br />
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="expand"></div> <!-- For demo purposes only -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add margin-top to the main div that is equal to the height of the fixed div. For example, if you have a 24px tall fixed div:

```
#fixed-div {
    position: fixed;
    height: 24px;
}

#main-div {
    margin-top: 24px;
}
```

Comment: The fixed div does not have a fixed height. The question has been edited but that was the same in the original edit. This answer will not work for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "position: relative" on the top div.

```
<div style="width: 100%; opacity: .6; position: fixed; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  background-color: #C0C0C0; position: relative;">
    fixed div line 1<br />
    fixed div line 2<br />
    fixed div line 3<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Ah - you added a second position parm, it already has one set to fixed. if I were to set the "fixed" div to relative, it will scroll with the page - the entire purpose is to have the fixed div remain in place regardless of the scrolling.

Comment: Also - if I want them spaced one after another, there is no need to specify any value for position: unless the div would be inheriting one from a parent. Leaving out the position: rule is the same as setting it to relative.

Comment: I should have said that not specifying position: is the same as setting it to relative - in this case. Depending upon other settings on other elements it may not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need a top margin on you main div with a value greater then your fixed divs height So if your fixed div is 60px high Make a margin-top:62px for the main div also you could get rid of margin-left and right and do all margins like this margin:60px auto;   if the 60px is no good for you on the bottom of the main div you could do margin:60px auto 0px auto;

Hope this helps
--Joshua Joseph Bissot

Answer (score 0):

Have good answer, curtsey of Joshua K.

I'll define a class named no-js (can be any class name) which sets position of 'fixed' div to relative. That will put the "fixed" div above the main div - though not actually fixed in place. Then with JavaScript I set the div to position: fixed and set the margin-top of the main div to the height of the "fixed" plus a fudge factor of say 5 or 6 px.

That way if JavaScript is enabled, the "fixed" div will actually be fixed and the margin-top of the main div will move it down to show the entire div.

If JavaScript is not enabled, the "fixed" div will still be visible, and above the main div, but it will scroll with the page.

Can I mark an answer as best answer? If so, how?

Stop the presses;

I could just set the position of the "fixed" div to relative (in a CSS class or using stye= on the element) and use JavaScript to change it to fixed and set the margin-top of the main div accordingly. That, I think, removes the need for another class named no-js or such.

---

I have created another page incorporating the changes needed to accomplish the task. It is at http://thetesting.site/fixeddiv/fixedheader-fixed.html